# Is possible to scale out Hashicorp Vault using DynamoDB storage backend?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, hashicorp-vault

I am using Vault on AWS with the DynamoDB backend. The backend supports HA.

```
storage "dynamodb" {
  ha_enabled = "true"
  region     = "us-west-2"
  table      = "vault-data"
}
```

Reading the HA concept documentation:
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/ha.html

> To be highly available, one of the Vault server nodes grabs a lock within the data store. The successful server node then becomes the active node; all other nodes become standby nodes. At this point, if the standby nodes receive a request, they will either forward the request or redirect the client depending on the current configuration and state of the cluster -- see the sections below for details. Due to this architecture, HA does not enable increased scalability.

I am not interested in having a fleet of EC2 instances behind a ELB, where only 1 instance behaves like a master and talks to DynamoDB.

I would like to run N Ec2 instances running Vault, that read and write independently from DynamoDB.

Because DynamoDB supports read/write from multiple EC2 instances, I would expect to be able to unseal Vault from multiple instances simultaneously and perform read and write operations. This should work even with `ha_enabled = "false"`, without doing the leader election.

Why this architecture is not suggested in the documentation ? Why it should not work ? Is there any cryptographic limitation that I am missing ?

thank you

Comment: great question, are you successful in setting this up?

Comment: I was able to ask this question to a Vault developer at the HashiConf EU in Amsterdam in 2019. He confirmed that multiple Vault EC2 instances must _not_ access the backend DynamoDB storage simultaneously, and that doing it could lead to unexpected problems.
I did not receive enough information to explain in detail where the limitation comes from. The suggested solution was to use Vault Enterprise that comes with features to support horizontal scalability.
I would still be very interested in understanding where the limit comes from.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of Vault Enterprise. With it, you can set up a primary cluster and as many "secondary" clusters, better known as performance replicas. Each cluster has its own storage and unseal mechanism. So you could have one cluster on Dynamo DB and the other on Raft. If both are on Dynamo DB, then you'll need a Dynamo DB table for each.

But keep in mind that **performance replicas will always forward write operations** to the primary cluster. A write operation is something that affect the global state of Vault. In that sense a POST to `/transit` is not considered a write operation.

Another possibility is to have your kv store mounted locally (with the `-local` flag). Then it will behave like a primary even when mounted on a performance replica, at the price of not being able to replicate to the other cluster.

A final note: DR clusters are an exact copy of any cluster. Each cluster, whether a primary or a replica, can have its DR cluster.